# Aerospike configure different filesize for each node

Tags: aerospike

Let's say we have 3 nodes A,B,C. Each having 15 GBs of filesize on disk. I want to bring up another node D but give it very little filesize size, because i will use this box only for data back up purpose. So I want to move to state

A 15GB,B 15GB, C 15GB, D 1GB

But I am not able to make it work, when i add the 4th node, it starts getting data which needs more filesize than what i have allocated. And process dies eventually.

Is it possible to configure different file sizes for each node in aerospike? While assigning bucket ranges to all the nodes, will the data distribution algorithm take file size into account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All nodes in the cluster are expected to be homogeneous with respect to capacity. See https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/setting-up-a-cluster-with-different-memory-sizes-on-nodes/4387

I would like to understand how having node D would help facilitate data backup.

Comment: there can be few use cases. lets say if total data size is 1TB, with 3 nodes, now to take back up i would need a box with 250GB + 1tb box (250 because when the box gets added to cluster, it will have to keep 1/4 th of data due to homogeneity.)

Comment: You wouldn't need to add the node to the cluster in order to take a backup, though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do but if on node D, you do not define the namespace you have on A, B and C, say *ns_dat*, and, you do need one namespace on D - call it *ns_temp*, then D will not have any data from *ns_dat*.  So, A, B, C are configured with namespace *ns_dat*, D is configured with *ns_temp*, and then D can be 1GB while A, B, C are 15GB. So you will have a 4 node cluster - what you want - and D will not take any data from A, B, C's namespace. *This is not a recommended way to configure Aerospike.* Again, not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: the use case is that when a cluster is very large, lets say 600gb and running on 3 nodes (so 200 gb data on each) to take a backup i am having to add another box with atleast 750GB disk space (600GB total data + 150GB because it gets its share of data from cluster) now if you see the problem will keep on increasing as the data size grows from 600gb to lets say 2tb.

Comment: So why are you adding the 4th node to the "Aerospike Cluster"? You can use asbackup tool ( https://docs.aerospike.com/tools/backup) and save data to disk on the fourth standalone machine. It will save just the master records copy so will use half the space assuming you have RF=2 on the Aerospike cluster.  If you have to restore the data back to the cluster, you can run asrestore companion tool to read from this 4th machine back to the 3 node Aerospike cluster.